# Increase and decrease the width of jquery mobile panel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile panel. I am adding content in panel.

```
$("#load").on("click", function () {
    var items = $("#p2 .ui-content").contents().clone();
    $(this).after(items);
});
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Lcbd2/

I want to decrease the width of panel but again get actual size when second time content added in panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Original size of the panel is `width: 17em;`.

To make the panels smaller using css.

```
.ui-panel {
width: 12em !important;
}
```

if you want to target a specific panel left or right

```
.ui-panel-position-right {
width: 12em !important;
}

.ui-panel-position-left{
width: 12em !important;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/ybvfxu39/

**Jquery**. As you now know the original size of the panel is **17em** you can use the below code to set a size when you need to.

```
$(".ui-panel-position-right").css("width", "12em");
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/z4k8L3vu/